# Replace section of copper heating-loop w/ pex

Tags: heating, pex, copper

I need to replace a short (less than 5 feet) of a 3/4" hydronic copper piping loop. Can I substitute 3/4" PEX for the copper?  Is there a flow-volume or any other issue?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm no expert, but if this is just to save the cost of copper it doesn't seem worthwhile to me.

Comment: Partly it's to get familiar w/ PEX.

Comment: What fittings will you use to go from copper to PEX and back?

Comment: I will use sharkbite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow shouldn't be an issue. You can check the table [here for copper](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pressure-loss-copper-pipes-d_930.html) and [here for PEX](https://www.rehau.com/download/868390/pexa-piping-pressure-loss-tables.pdf) to see how much pressure you'll lose per a given length of pipe. Copper and PEX are very similar.